# Does Redshift distribute by DISTKEY sequentially?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a Redshift table with page hits, like so

```
CREATE TABLE hits
(
  user_id INT,
  ts TIMESTAMP,
  page VARCHAR(255)
)
SORTKEY(user_id, ts)
DISTKEY(user_id);
```

Since I'll be running a bunch of window functions over `user_id`, I thought it would be a good idea to distribute the table by `user_id` so nodes don't have to exchange data on users before being able to execute the query.

But the users are only ever active for some time and are numbered sequentially. user_id and time are therefore correlated so whenever I run a query that subsets by time (`ts`) this will lead to skew if Redshift also distributes by `user_id` sequentially. This would be less of a problem if it distributed by the `DISTKEY` randomly. My question is: does it?

(I'm new to Redshift so all of this may just be a total misunderstanding of how things work in general. In that case, apologies in advance!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon Redshift uses a **hash of the DISTRIBUTION KEY (DISTKEY)** to distribute data records amongst nodes.

Thus, records will be distributed differently on a 3-node cluster than a 4-node cluster.

If you are seeking evenly-distributed data, use the `EVEN` distribution method, which simply spreads records evenly between nodes. (However, this is unlikely to be optimal for your use-case.)

See documentation:

- [Choose the Best Distribution Style](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-best-dist-key.html)
- [Amazon Redshift Best Practices for Designing Tables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_designing-tables-best-practices.html)

Comment: Just to understand this a bit better: If I have two separate tables that have identical column names and types and that share some values in one of the columns. If I set this column as the DISTKEY, will rows that have the same value on the DISTKEY end up on the same node independent of the table they are in?

Comment: I believe that is true, but I can't find any documentation that specifically says it that way. The Value is passed through a hash function that then distributes content across nodes. The column name does not need to match, it only uses the value of the field.

Comment: @RoyalTS yes, rows with the same DISTKEY values end up on the same nodes, which enables `merge` join. See [query plan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-the-query-plan.html) doc, especially the section on join types, for information on `merge` vs `hash` joins.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Could we get a citation for the fact that Redshift uses a hash of distribution key to distribute data records? It makes sense that they would, but I don't see any documentation of that design choice in the links here.

Comment: @andrew There are probably other references, but I found a mention on [Amazon Redshift Engineering’s Advanced Table Design Playbook: Distribution Styles and Distribution Keys | AWS Big Data Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/amazon-redshift-engineerings-advanced-table-design-playbook-distribution-styles-and-distribution-keys/) (written by a developer on the Redshift team). It's a great article, too!

Comment: This is a great resource thank you @JohnRotenstein!